# How to perform vector_query in multiple fields?

Tags: typesense

I am creating a mobile app which users can create clubs. When they create these clubs they have to assign 3 tags which are descriptive of what that club is about, per example, a tennis club would probably have the tags [“tennis”, “sports”, “amateur”].

I am creating embeddings using openAI, and then I store these vectors in Typesense documents. Each document represents a club.

Right now each document has 3 vectors which represent each one of the tags.

QUESTION:

How can I to a vector_queey which takes into account all 3 vector fields? In normal queries I can just make several queries and then do query_weights but with vectors I don’t know how to do this?